# Antiderivatives - part c, solving for x

Tags: calculus, integration

$MR(x)=4x(x^2+26,000)^{-2/3}$

I'm already lost at the part $2\int u^{-2/3}$ How did they get $6u^{1/3}+C$

a)Find the revenue function

b) What is the revenue from selling 250 ​gadgets?
​

c) How many gadgets must be sold for a revenue of at least ​$50​,000?

Solve for x. (How?)

$6(x^2+26,000)^{1/3}-150=50$

Comment: Please always include your own attempt at solving the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any $r \neq -1$, $\int x^r dx = \frac{1}{r+1}x^{r+1} + C$. This is just the reverse of the derivative $\frac{d}{dx}x^r = rx^{r - 1}$. Set $r = -\frac{2}{3}$ and you get the integral you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you, I used that earlier but don't know what I did to get the wrong answer